# iOS - A UIScrollView with very large content view, how to reduce the memory usage?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit

The content view must contains lots of text(CATextLayer) and curves(CAShapeLayer).

If the content is too large, the app will crash because using memory too much.

Answer (score 1):

Use a collection view or table view so that content outside the screen's bounds isn't rendered thus saving memory. Also the cells will be reused.

Another solution could be continuing to use scroll view, but implementing this off screen reuse pattern yourself.